# Are questions about RPG related comics on topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

Inevitably a question has been asked on [the main trilogy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/) about comics that are very tangential to the topic of the site and although they generally get good upvotes they create a lot of controversy.  Since I had a few [Knights](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ow1zRZR5Dao#t=1m50s) [of](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5g337Imvlc#t=43s) [the](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmzWd0eik44) [Dinner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpgqZ3JoRIc#t=1m43s) [Table](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRshMRyRrgs) lines pop into my head earlier as I was looking over questions I figured I'd double check how the community felt about a wiki question on it first.

Because we all know that at some point the [gazebo](http://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/98/Jul/gazebo.html) or [casting magic missiles at the darkness](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zng5kRle4FA) will be mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. One thing worth considering here is that a lot of times those novels/comics can be canon for the setting, and thus are in some ways a form of sourcebook.  If the question is referencing the novels/comics in this way, I would say on topic.  If it's more about the novels/comics themselves, then OT.

Comment: After some time, I have come to agree with this. Game setting questions are on topic; where a game setting is also explored in a book it's on topic - as long as it's a question in the context of an RPG.

Answer (score 5):

I think that's gotta be off-topic. Come to think of it, the question about RPG novels might have been slightly off-topic as well, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I would say absolutely not on the computer RPGs - that's going to be one of the main points of confusion with this over time, as hordes of CRPGers happen across this and assume it's for CRPGs (there's 1000 of them for every 1 of us).

For the comics and books...  I personally don't think so, but I'm on the fence.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about characters and environment should probably head over to the [Sci-Fi and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). Questions about for instance, *Why does Elan think taking off his clothes will make him invisible?* are probably more suited to here.

Comment: Yes, and +1 for OotS!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know.

While this is not the principal subject of rpg@stackexchange, they are still tied to RPGs and should be authorized.

I wonder if questions/answers about some computer RPGs should be authorized. For example, Bioware is famous for adding a lot of character development (even if the recipes never strays far from a standard one). Am I authorized to ask questions about their "dialog tree" technic and how it could be applied in tabletop RPGs? Or even to ask if Loghain (from Dragon Age) is a credible NPC ?

I would answer yes, but I'm still unsure...